# How can the actual displayed language's culture info be retrieved in Windows Phone?

Tags: localization, windows-phone

If the selected phone language isn't supported by an application it will fall back to the neutral language. How can this be detected in code? The `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` will always return the language selected in the phone settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this goal could be to add a string to each resource file with the culture identifier of it. That is, add an entry to the resource file, for example with the name `ResourceLanguage` and the value (e.g. "en-US" if English etc.).

Then you can retrieve the value in your code:

```cs
var language = AppResources.ResourceLanguage;
```